# Using "which" R programming image processing

Tags: r

Input binary image http://s21.postimg.org/qba3sqkx3/binary_image.jpg
Extract all indices which have '1's differentiating from background 0s

```
#using R code: 
indices=which(binary_image==1,arr.ind = TRUE);

#Extract rows and columns of vasculature_indices:
rowindices=indices[,1];
colindices=indices[,2];

# Check if all the foreground regions indices were extracted:
binary_image[rowindices,colindices]=0;
```

Display the resultant binary_image, I expect a complete black out image

```
display(binary_image,method="raster",all=TRUE);
```

Output produced: http://s15.postimg.org/xjrj1ex8b/output.jpg

My conclusion: Not all indices of the foreground regions in the input binary_image were extracted.

Please correct me if I have any mistakes in my code.

Comment: I don't see a difference? Why do you expect a difference?

Comment: Because I set the values in extracted foreground indices to Zero. Hence, I should be seeing a complete black picture in other words I removed all the white foregrounds of the input binary_image.

Comment: This question will be closed, as the poster realised that the input binary_image is not a binary image. There is fundamentally wrong in the starting assumption made by the poster.

Comment: You third comment says _# Check if .._ but, instead, you seem to be setting to 0. Also, note that `binary_image[rowindices, colindices] != binary_image[cbind(rowindices, colindices)]`; unless I'm missing something you were looking for the second?